# I want connect.php file should be run in local host. But as follow error there

Tags: php

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in D:\xampp\htdocs\ngp\connect.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\xampp\htdocs\ngp\connect.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in D:\xampp\htdocs\ngp\connect.php on line 4

Answer (score 1):

This means that the username/password in your connection file is wrong, or that access to the server is not allowed from the machine you're trying to connect from.

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that the user `test` and the password you used were not valid and the user `ODBC` using no password was invalid. Either because they are just wrong or because the users are not allowed to connect from the machine you are connecting from. E.g. if you are connecting remotely from your local machine to a hosted machine.

Check the MySql usernames and passwords you have set up to connect to your database.

Also, show some code!